# Best way to create a flocking algorithm for a group of foxes chasing a rabbit

Tags: c++

The program is updating constantly every frame and its making it difficult to calculate the distance between a fox and the rabbit.(it will be an almost identical value)

I have tried using doubles so that distance value would compensate for a small change but that hasn't worked.

```
define OLC_PGE_APPLICATION
#include "olcPixelGameEngine.h"

int x = 0;
class Example : public olc::PixelGameEngine
{
private:
    olc::Sprite* rabbit;
    olc::Sprite* bush;
    olc::Sprite* fox;
    olc::Sprite* evilfox;
    int size = 3;
    double rabbitPosX = 30.0;
    double rabbitPosY = 30.0;
    double rabbitXvel = 0.0;
    double rabbitYvel = 0.0;
    double FoxPosX[3] = { 50.0f,80.0f,70.0};
    double FoxPosY[3] = { 80.0f,50.0f,200.0};
    double FoxXvel = 0.0;
    double FoxYvel = 0.0;

public:
    Example()
    {
        sAppName = "Example";
    }

public:
    double distanceForm(double x1, double x2, double y1, double y2)
    {
        double distance = sqrt((x2 - x1)*(x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1)*(y2 - y1));
        return distance;
    }
    bool checkCurFox(double arrX[], double arrY[], int size, int count)
    {       
        for (int i = count+1; i < size; i++)
        {
            if (distanceForm(arrX[count], arrX[i], arrY[count], arrY[i]) > 15)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

    }
    double moveRabbitX(double rabbitX, double VelX, double ETime)
    {
        if (VelX > 0)
        {
            double NewrabbitX = rabbitX + VelX * ETime;
            return NewrabbitX;
        }
        double NewrabbitX = rabbitX + VelX * ETime;
        return NewrabbitX;
    }
    double moveRabbitY(double rabbitY, double VelY, double ETime)
    {
        if (VelY > 0)
        {
            double NewrabbitY = rabbitY + VelY * ETime;
            return NewrabbitY;
        }
        double NewrabbitY = rabbitY + VelY * ETime;
        return NewrabbitY;      
    }
    double moveFoxX(double FoxX, double VelX, double ETime)
    {
        if (VelX > 0)
        {
            double NewFoxX = FoxX + VelX * ETime;
            return NewFoxX;
        }
        double NewFoxX = FoxX + VelX * ETime;
        return NewFoxX;
    }
    double moveFoxY(double FoxY, double VelY, double ETime)
    {
        if (VelY > 0)
        {
            double NewFoxY = FoxY + VelY * ETime;
            return NewFoxY;
        }
        double NewFoxY = FoxY + VelY * ETime;
        return NewFoxY;

    }
    bool OnUserCreate() override
    {
        // Called once at the start, so create things here  
        //DrawRect(0,0,ScreenWidth(),ScreenHeight(),olc::DARK_VERY_DARK_GREEN);

        /*DrawSprite(30,40,)*/
        FillRect(0, 0, ScreenWidth(), ScreenHeight(), olc::VERY_DARK_GREEN);
        DrawString(80, 0, "Fox Escape", olc::RED, 1);
        rabbit =new olc::Sprite("Rabbit.png");
        DrawSprite(30, 30, rabbit,1);
        /*bush = new olc::Sprite("Bush.png");
        DrawSprite(50, 50, bush, 2);*/
        fox = new olc::Sprite("Fox.png");
        //DrawSprite(50, 70, fox, 1);
        evilfox = new olc::Sprite("evilfox.png");   
        return true;
    }
    bool OnUserUpdate(float fElapsedTime) override
    {

        int Omg = 1;
        // called once per frame
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            double distance = distanceForm(rabbitPosX, FoxPosX[j], rabbitPosY, FoxPosY[j]);
            double distanceMxUp = distanceForm(rabbitPosX, FoxPosX[j], rabbitPosY, moveFoxY(FoxPosY[j], -20, fElapsedTime));
            double distanceMxDown = distanceForm(rabbitPosX, FoxPosX[j], rabbitPosY, moveFoxY(FoxPosY[j], +20, fElapsedTime));
            double distanceMyRight = distanceForm(moveFoxX(FoxPosX[j], 20, fElapsedTime), rabbitPosX, FoxPosY[j], rabbitPosY);
            double distanceMyLeft = distanceForm(moveFoxX(FoxPosX[j], -20, fElapsedTime), rabbitPosX, FoxPosY[j], rabbitPosY);

            double arr[4] = { distanceMxUp,distanceMxDown,distanceMyRight,distanceMyLeft };
            double temp;
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    if (arr[i] > arr[j])
                    {
                        temp = arr[i];
                        arr[i] = arr[j];
                        arr[j] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
            int tempX = FoxPosX[j];
            int tempY = FoxPosY[j];
            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
            {
                if (checkCurFox(FoxPosX, FoxPosY, size, j))
                {
                    if (arr[k] == distanceMxUp)
                    {
                        k = 3;
                        double NewFoxY = moveFoxY(FoxPosY[j], -10, fElapsedTime);
                        FillRect(FoxPosX[j], FoxPosY[j], 15, 15, olc::VERY_DARK_GREEN);
                        FoxPosY[j] = NewFoxY;
                        DrawSprite(FoxPosX[j], FoxPosY[j], fox, 1);
                        if (distance < 6)
                        {
                            FillRect(0, 0, ScreenWidth(), ScreenHeight(), olc::Pixel(0, 0, 0));
                            DrawSprite(0, 0, evilfox, 1);
                        }
                    }
                    if (arr[k] == distanceMxDown)
                    {
                        k = 3;
                        double NewFoxY = moveFoxY(FoxPosY[j], 10, fElapsedTime);
                        FillRect(FoxPosX[j], FoxPosY[j], 15, 15, olc::VERY_DARK_GREEN);
                        FoxPosY[j] = NewFoxY;
                        DrawSprite(FoxPosX[j], FoxPosY[j], fox, 1);
                        if (distance < 6)
                        {
                            FillRect(0, 0, ScreenWidth(), ScreenHeight(), olc::Pixel(0, 0, 0));
                            DrawSprite(0, 0, evilfox, 1);
                        }
                    }
                    if (arr[k] == distanceMyRight)
                    {
                        k = 3;
                        double NewFoxX = moveFoxX(FoxPosX[j], 10, fElapsedTime);
                        FillRect(FoxPosX[j], FoxPosY[j], 15, 15, olc::VERY_DARK_GREEN);
                        FoxPosX[j] = NewFoxX;
                        DrawSprite(FoxPosX[j], FoxPosY[j], fox, 1);
                        if (distance < 6)
                        {
                            FillRect(0, 0, ScreenWidth(), ScreenHeight(), olc::Pixel(0, 0, 0));
                            DrawSprite(0, 0, evilfox, 1);
                        }
                    }
                    if (arr[k] == distanceMyLeft)
                    {
                        k = 3;
                        double NewFoxX = moveFoxX(FoxPosX[j], -10, fElapsedTime);
                        FillRect(FoxPosX[j], FoxPosY[j], 15, 15, olc::VERY_DARK_GREEN);
                        FoxPosX[j] = NewFoxX;
                        DrawSprite(FoxPosX[j], FoxPosY[j], fox, 1);
                        if (distance < 6)
                        {
                            FillRect(0, 0, ScreenWidth(), ScreenHeight(), olc::Pixel(0, 0, 0));
                            DrawSprite(0, 0, evilfox, 1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (GetKey(olc::Key::RIGHT).bHeld)
        {
            rabbitXvel = 30.0f;
            double NewrabbitX = moveRabbitX(rabbitPosX, rabbitXvel, fElapsedTime);
            FillRect(rabbitPosX, rabbitPosY, 7, 8,olc::VERY_DARK_GREEN);
            rabbitPosX = NewrabbitX;
            DrawSprite(rabbitPosX, rabbitPosY, rabbit);     
        }
        if (GetKey(olc::Key::LEFT).bHeld)
        {
            rabbitXvel = -30.0f;
            double NewrabbitX = moveRabbitX(rabbitPosX, rabbitXvel, fElapsedTime);
            FillRect(rabbitPosX, rabbitPosY, 7, 8, olc::VERY_DARK_GREEN);
            rabbitPosX = NewrabbitX;
            DrawSprite(rabbitPosX, rabbitPosY, rabbit);
        }
        if (GetKey(olc::Key::UP).bHeld)
        {
            rabbitYvel = -30.0f;
            double NewrabbitY = moveRabbitY(rabbitPosY, rabbitYvel, fElapsedTime);
            FillRect(rabbitPosX, rabbitPosY, 7, 8, olc::VERY_DARK_GREEN);
            rabbitPosY = NewrabbitY;
            DrawSprite(rabbitPosX, rabbitPosY, rabbit);

        }
        if (GetKey(olc::Key::DOWN).bHeld)
        {
            rabbitYvel = 30.0f;
            double NewrabbitY = moveRabbitY(rabbitPosY, rabbitYvel, fElapsedTime);
            FillRect(rabbitPosX, rabbitPosY, 7, 8, olc::VERY_DARK_GREEN);
            rabbitPosY = NewrabbitY;
            DrawSprite(rabbitPosX, rabbitPosY, rabbit);

        }

        //Draw(rabbitPosX, rabbitPosY, olc::YELLOW);

        return true;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Example demo;
    if (demo.Construct(256, 240, 4, 4))
        demo.Start();

    return 0;
}
```

I want the foxes to avoid colliding with each other.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what problem you are having. What is the result of the above code and how is it different than what you desire? That being said, using == to compare floating point numbers is asking for trouble. See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html Also, it would be a good idea to separate the logic of your flocking algorithm from the GUI. This makes the code clearer and allows it to be tested independently.

Comment: @pcarter The result is the foxes move up to the rabbit but only up as it is first to be processed. This is because the difference is so small because the time elapsed is in micro seconds.

Comment: You also have a whole lot of positioning/moving logic crammed in. Try to separate that from the "fun" part of the code. [Example @ godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/YC3nYZ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple months back, I stumbled upon [this terrific blog post](http://harry.me/blog/2011/02/17/neat-algorithms-flocking/), which explains the "boid" flocking behavior. To create lifelike movement in your foxes, there's a few things you'll need to do. A quick summary:

- Every fox needs to be aware of the rabbit, so they can follow it around.
- Every fox needs to be aware of every other fox, so they can behave properly. You only mention moving apart from one another (separation), but there's a few more options:

  - **Separation** is a behavior where, if a fox moves to close to another fox, both of them try to drift apart.
  - **Cohesion** is a behavior where, if there is a "group" of foxes together, each one tries to move towards the center of the group.
  - **Alignment** is a behavior where, if a fox encounters a group moving in a certain direction, it will try to match that direction.

For your example, if the foxes are strictly behaving to chase the rabbit and stay apart from one another, you'll want to use separation. Here's what the pseudocode might look like, if you store the foxes in an array.

```
fox foxarray[size_of_array]
rabbit rabb

//separate the foxes if they get too close
for(each fox in foxarray) {
  current_fox = //the fox you're checking
  for(every other fox in foxarray) {
    other_fox = //the other ones you'll look at

    if(distanceFrom(current_fox, other_fox) < some_threshold_value) {
      /*
      use a function to check the positions of the foxes,
      and then adjust their velocities to move away from 
      one another.
      */
      move_apart(curernt_fox, other_fox) 
    }
  }
}

//chase the rabbit
for(each fox in foxarray) {
  current_fox = //the fox you're checking
/*
this would check their positions, and then adjust the fox's velocity 
to move it towards the rabbit. 
i'm assuming the rabbit is player-controlled, so its velocity
wouldn't be changed
*/
  move_towards(current_fox, rabb) 
}
```

But what about the functions?

```
void move_apart(fox f1, fox f2) {

  //set f1's velocity away from f2
  //first, get f2's position relative to f1, then add velocity
  //to move away from it
  f2xPos = f2.x - f1.x;
  f2yPos = f2.y - f1.y;


  if(f2xPos < 0) {
    //if f2xPos is negative, add some positive x velocity to move away
    f1xVel += some_velocity;
  }
  else {
    //add some negative velocity to move away
    f1xVel -= some_velocity;
  }

  //repeat for f2 - or, alternatively, call move_apart() with
  //f2 and f1 flipped.

}

//============================================================

void move_towards(fox f, rabbit r) {

  //very similar to move_apart, but you'd flip the signs of
  //the velocity so you can move the fox towards the rabbit.

}
```

These are just bare-bones examples, and I've found that much better movement can be achieved if you factor in how far apart the foxes are from one another, i.e. the closer they are, the faster they try to move apart. I also find that if you represent their positions and velocities as 2D vectors (the <x, y> kind, not the `std::vector` self-expanding arrays) it becomes easier to manage them.

If you're willing to refactor your code and/or are planning to make the game bigger, I very strongly recommend separating the moving entities (foxes and rabbits) into their own classes, instead of arrays of doubles in your engine class. This makes it much, much easier to implement the entities' functions, change their behaviors, and keep track of their positions and velocities.

Additionally, if you're encountering framerate issues with the program furiously checking the positions of the foxes every frame at hundreds of frames per second, maybe consider `usleep()` between frames to slow down the execution.

Good luck with your game!